# How to stop one or multiple for loop(s)

Tags: python

I want to determine if every element in my n x n list is the same. i.e. `[[0,0],[0,0]]` returns true but `[[0,1],[0,0]]` will return false. I was thinking of stoping immediately when I find an element that is not the same as the first element. i.e:

```
n=L[0][0]
m=len(A)
for i in range(m):
 for j in range(m):
   if
    L[i][j]==n: -continue the loop-
   else: -stop the loop-
```

I would like to stop this loop if `L[i][j]!==n`  and return false, otherwise return true. How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use `break` and `continue` to do this. Breaking nested loops can be done in Python using the following:

```
for a in range(...):
   for b in range(..):
      if some condition:
         # break the inner loop
         break
   else:
      # will be called if the previous loop did not end with a `break` 
      continue
   # but here we end up right after breaking the inner loop, so we can
   # simply break the outer loop as well
   break
```

Another way is to wrap everything in a function and use `return` to escape from the loop.

Comment: Wow, wish C# had that `for...else` construct!

Comment: Oh, I wish the very same for C++, Java, .. :-)

Comment: I'm trying to get the function to return a value before the break but I keep getting a warning saying the break will never be reached

Comment: +1 for the creative answer, but is it really worth it ? You can simply make if found: break. Shorter, easier to read.

Comment: Best thing is, retype it and don't try to copy&paste - Python screws up badly on indentation problems.

Comment: oh I see what you said about the return. I didn't know return escapes a loop thanks a lot!

Answer (score 67):

There are several ways to do it:

## The simple Way: a sentinel variable

```
n = L[0][0]
m = len(A)
found = False
for i in range(m):
   if found:
      break
   for j in range(m):
     if L[i][j] != n: 
       found = True
       break
```

Pros: easy to understand
Cons: additional conditional statement for every loop

## The hacky Way: raising an exception

```
n = L[0][0]
m = len(A)

try:
  for x in range(3):
    for z in range(3):
     if L[i][j] != n: 
       raise StopIteration
except StopIteration:
   pass
```

Pros: very straightforward
Cons: you use Exception outside of their semantic

## The clean Way: make a function

```
def is_different_value(l, elem, size):
  for x in range(size):
    for z in range(size):
     if l[i][j] != elem: 
       return True
  return False
   
if is_different_value(L, L[0][0], len(A)):
  print "Doh"
```

pros: much cleaner and still efficient
cons: yet feels like C

## The pythonic way: use iteration as it should be

```
def is_different_value(iterable):
  first = iterable[0][0]
  for l in iterable:
    for elem in l:
       if elem != first: 
          return True
  return False
   
if is_different_value(L):
  print "Doh"
```

pros: still clean and efficient
cons: you reinvdent the wheel

## The guru way: use `any()`:

```
def is_different_value(iterable):
  first = iterable[0][0]
  return any(cell != first for col in iterable for cell in col)

if is_different_value(L):
  print "Doh"
```

pros: you'll feel empowered with dark powers
cons: people that will read you code may start to dislike you

Comment: +1 for the guru way (no ok, great answer anyway but really liked the pros and cons of the guru way)

Comment: I liked the *hacky* way.

Answer (score 4):

Try to simply use [break](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement.

Also you can use the following code as an example:

```
a = [[0,1,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,1]]
b = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]

def check_matr(matr, expVal):    
    for row in matr:
        if len(set(row)) > 1 or set(row).pop() != expVal:
            print 'Wrong'
            break# or return
        else:
            print 'ok'
    else:
        print 'empty'
check_matr(a, 0)
check_matr(b, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the break statement: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#break

Answer (score 0):

Others ways to do the same is:

```
el = L[0][0]
m=len(L)

print L == [[el]*m]*m
```

Or:

```
first_el = L[0][0]
print all(el == first_el for inner_list in L for el in inner_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you would do something like:

```
n=L[0][0]
m=len(A)
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(m):
        if L[i][j]==n:
            //do some processing
        else:
            break;
```

Answer (score -2):

In order to jump out of a loop, you need to use the break statement.

```
n=L[0][0]
m=len(A)
for i in range(m):
 for j in range(m):
   if L[i][j]!=n:
       break;
```

Here you have the official Python manual with the explanation about break and continue, and other flow control statements:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html

EDITED: As a commenter pointed out, this does only end the inner loop. If you need to terminate both loops, there is no "easy" way (others have given you a few solutions). One possiblity would be to raise an exception:

```
def f(L, A):
    try:
        n=L[0][0]
        m=len(A)
        for i in range(m):
             for j in range(m):
                 if L[i][j]!=n:
                     raise RuntimeError( "Not equal" )
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: You are breaking just the inner for loop, and using semicolon is unnecessary and ugly.

Answer (score -2):

To stop your loop you can use ***break*** with ***label***. It will stop your loop for sure. Code is written in Java but aproach is the same for the all languages.

```
public void exitFromTheLoop() {
    boolean value = true;
            loop_label:for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              if(!value) { 
                 System.out.println("iteration: " + i);
              break loop_label;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: looks like your answer is written in C++ or JS but the question is in Python

Comment: Hello Falco, and welcome to SO. Please, take your time and format code properly in your answer. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25805886#) it.

Answer (score -2):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but if that could help anyone else, here's my answer:

I find it easier to understand with the use of a ***while*** loop and it will stop both *for* loops that way. The code below also return the True/False as asked when the function *check_nxn_list()* is called. Some parameters may have to be added in the function call.

```
def check_nxn_list():
    state = True
    n=L[0][0]
    m=len(A)
    while state == True:
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(m):
                if L[i][j]!=n:
                    state = False
        break
    return state
```

The ***break*** at the end of the *while* loop is required to end the loop even if *state* stays *True*.

Comment: that is nonsense.  The point is avoiding going over the quadratic combination produced by the two nested 'for' .  Adding the break outside them is completely useless, and equivalent to not having the while nor the break