# a code with for loops and if statements that displays the wrong message

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

When I run this code it still shows up with the "search unsuccessful" message, could anyone help me figure out why? I know that it has a loop in it but I cannot figure out how to make the code stop looping once it has found all of the positions of the word in the sentence.

```
    sentence= "the hat ran away from the cat"
    print(sentence)
    word_to_find= input("write word from sentence")
    senLow= sentence.lower()
    word= word_to_find.lower() 
    senList= senLow.split()

    for pos in range(len(senList)):
        if word== senList[pos]:
            print(word, "found in position:", pos+1)

    else :
       print ("search unsuccessful")
```

Comment: Please pose the relevant code here, as text.

Comment: sentence= "the hat ran away from the cat"
print(sentence)
word_to_find= input("write word from sentence")
senLow= sentence.lower()
word= word_to_find.lower() 
senList= senLow.split()

for pos in range(len(senList)):
    if word== senList[pos]:
        print(word, "found in position:", pos+1)

else :
    print ("seacrh unsuccessful")

Comment: Your `else` is being applied to the `for` statement, no the `if` statement. It will always execute unless you break out of the loop.

Comment: @jackd No! Edit the question and post your code *there*.

Comment: @jackd Don you actually expect that anyone's going to be able to read that? Edit it into the question, highlight it, and press ctrl+k.

Comment: Yeah, so this code would work if you put a `break` after your `print`.

Comment: sorry i've done it now

Comment: Ok, now I think this is simply a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346492/how-to-stop-a-for-loop
Or not. You cannot "stop looping once it has found all the positions of the word in the sentence" because there is no way to know until you've looped through the entire sentence!

Comment: when i put a break it only displays the position of the first time the word is in the sentence so if for example i input "the" it only says that its in position 1 but it also appears later in the sentence

Comment: Right. So what exactly is your question? Remove the `else` block from your `for-loop`, that's definitely wrong. Especially if you are not going to use `break`. Then maybe keep a flag, something like `found = False` and then if you do find something, just use `found = True`, and after your loop, `if not found: print("search unsuccessful")`

Comment: thank you it works now! your help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sentence = "the hat ran away from the cat"
print(sentence)
word_to_find = input("write word from sentence")
senLow = sentence.lower()
word = word_to_find.lower()
senList = senLow.split()
found = False
for pos in range(len(senList)):
    if word == senList[pos]:
        print(word, "found in position:", pos+1)
        found = True

if not found:
    print ("seacrh unsuccessful")
```

I added a flag 'found' which will be set to true if word occur in the sentence, otherwise 'seacrh unsuccessful' will be print.

Comment: This will print search unsuccessful afterchecking each word, which is probably undesirable.