# Is there a way to stop my loop once I have printed a certain amount of numbers in python?

Tags: python

I am creating a code in Python to get the 10001st prime number, and I am looking for a way to stop printing numbers once I have printed 10001 numbers. Is this possible?

Comment: This is the most basic functionality of any programming language. Hint: "+= 1" and "if"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346492/how-to-stop-a-for-loop)

Comment: You can use [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, you can create a variable before your loop, and everytime that it gets a prime number, you add 1 to it, then check if it is the 10001st number already to break the loop. Or even something like that:

```
currentPrime = 0
while currentPrime < 10001:
    #Do your checks here to see if it's a prime, and if it is, do the following code:
    currentPrime = currentPrime + 1
```

There's many ways to do it so just find the one that suits you better.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `break` inside your for loop which will exit the loop. You'll have to include an if/then statement to `break` after 10001

Answer (score 1):

A while loop would work here:

```
primes = []
while len(primes) < 10001:
    #some code to find and print the next prime
    primes.append(next_prime)
```