# How to break between loop by creating a condition in python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, break

```
lst = []
while True:
    try:
        arr = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))
        if arr == "Quit":
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:
    try:
        for i in range(0, arr):
            ele = int(input("Enter the elements:"))
            lst.append(ele)
            print(lst)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

How can I create a condition to exit the program at any point in the loop by specifically entering the conditioned term?
Like when it asks me to enter an element, but i want to break the program right at that point by entering
"Quit".
How to do that in this code?
(Learner)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to stop a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346492/how-to-stop-a-for-loop)

Comment: @MykolaZotko They said exit the program.

Comment: Your question/code/goal is unclear. If you simply want to exit the program, then do so as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/how-to-terminate-a-python-script).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) to exit the program *completely*. Use `break` to exit the specific loop you're in (which you've used).

Other notes:

1. You're doing `arr = int(input(...))` but you want to accept the input of `"Quit"` which is a string. So if the user enters "Quit", it raise `ValueError` and the loop continues. So check for "Quit" first and if it's not quit, then convert to `int` with the try-block

   - Same applies for the 2nd loop where you ask the user for the elements in the list
2. Btw, your second loop's `while True` loop should be inside the for-loop which gets each element.

```py
lst = []
while True:
    arr = input("Enter number of elements: ")
    if arr == "Quit":
        sys.exit()  # will exit completely
    try:
        arr = int(arr)  # check for int in the try-block, error raised here, if not int
        break           # can put break here instead of in else, any is okay
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input")
        # continue not needed here, since it loops infinitely by default


for i in range(0, arr):
    while True:
        ele = input("Enter the elements:")
        if ele == "Quit":
            sys.exit()  # will exit completely
        try:
            ele = int(ele)  # check for int in the try-block, error raised here, if not int
            lst.append(ele)
            break           # breaks out of `while` loop, not `for` loop; good
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Input")
            # continue not needed here, since it loops infinitely by default

print(lst)  # print the full list after all the inputs
```

The pattern for your input is repeated:

- Ask user for input
- if input is "Quit", then exit completely
- otherwise, convert the input to an int

So this can put into a function, which you call in both places:

```py
def int_or_quit(msg):
    """`msg` is the message you want to show at input"""
    while True:
        item = input(msg)
        if item == "Quit":
            sys.quit()  # will exit completely
        try:
            return int(item)  # try converting to int and return
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Input")
            # repeats by default

# use the function above in your two code blocks, which are now simplified:
lst = []
arr = int_or_quit("Enter number of elements: ")
# program exits before if user "Quit", next part won't execute

for i in range(0, arr):
    ele = int_or_quit("Enter an element:")
    lst.append(ele)

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that there're 2 blocks in your code snippet. I'd suggest organising them in distinct functions, where function name infers a function goal (instead of comments):

```
def get_list_size():...
def fill_list():...
```

Next thing to do is deciding about function's return values:

```
from typing import List, Optional

def get_list_size() -> Optional[int]:
"""
:returns: number of desired elements of list or None, if "Quit" was pressed
:raises: ValueError exception, if non integer value was pressed
"""

def fill_list(lst_size: int) -> List[int]:
"""
returns: filled list
throws: ValueError exception, if non integer value was pressed
"""
```

Here you can see, how Optional type hint is used to add condition logic into the program.
Lats thing to do is to fill your functions with lightweight code:

```
def get_list_size() -> Optional[int]:
    """
    :returns: number of desired elements of list or None, if "Quit" was pressed
    :raises: ValueError exception, if non integer value was pressed
    """
    while True:
        try:
            input_value = input("Enter number of elements: ")

            # Pay attention: you have to check string input_value, not    int(input_value).
            # Checking int(input_value) would raise exception before 'Quit' validation.
            if input_value == "Quit":
                return None

            return int(input_value)

            # Could be rewritten as trinary if
            # return None if input_value == "Quit" else int(input_value)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Input")
            # continue <- Not needed here


def fill_list(lst_size: int) -> List[int]:
    """
    returns: filled list
    throws: ValueError exception, if non integer value was pressed
    """
    lst = []
    while len(lst) < lst_size:
        try:
            ele = int(input("Enter the elements:"))
            lst.append(ele)
            print(lst)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Input")
        
    return lst
```

Pay attention: in fill_list function you have to try/except each element, so while loop was moved outside.
Last thing to do is running these functions:

```
desired_list = []
desired_list_size = get_list_size()
if desired_list_size is not None:
    desired_list = fill_list(desired_list_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def one():
    message = ""
    while message != "Quit":
        message = input("Type in Order > ")
        if message == "Run":
            print("Run some Code")
            message = input("What do u want to run ? > ")
            if message == "Exel":
                print("Runing Exel")
            else:
                pass
         else:
             pass

while True:
    one()
```

Here you can pass in funktions that will run when you call it by its Name. If u write Quit it will start over again. It starts over again if you write something wrong. U could do an FailExeption for that if u want to.