# Stopping a loop once it evaluates to true

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

Assume a text file named "File1.txt" has the following structure:

```
random information
data #29, 45392 records
Unit: Unit1  Location: AA11
2011-09-20 14:06:20.78 28 finished
more random info
2017-04-19 09:11:59.00 00:01:02.30 A24    8     7
2017-04-19 09:12:02.25 00:00:01.00 A22    3     3
```

We want to collect the name of the unit from this data (which is `Unit1` in this case, as seen on the 3rd line of the file), so that we can refer to its value and store it in a dataframe. We can accomplish that with the following code:

```
un = [] #to store unit name
with open("File1.txt","r") as fi:
    for line in fi:
        if line.startswith("Unit"):
            un.append(line.split()[1])
# we could then create a dataframe and populate it with the value of un as needed
```

Now what if the text file (from the same "unit") has more than one line that starts with `Unit`:

```
random information
data #29, 45392 records
Unit: Unit1  Location: AA11
2011-09-20 14:06:20.78 28 finished
more random info
2017-04-19 09:11:59.00 00:01:02.30 A24    8     7
2017-04-19 09:12:02.25 00:00:01.00 A22    3     3
Unit: Unit1  Location: AA11
```

Both lines that start with `Unit` contain the same information (i.e., the name of our unit: `Unit1`), so we only need to collect the name one time. In this case, using the script above would result in a list with two elements (`Unit1` would be repeated twice). How can we essentially tell the loop to stop once it evaluates to true?

Comment: Are you familiar with the break command?

Comment: This is basic loop control.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  `un = line.split()[1] ... break` does the job.

Comment: IMO conceptually you want a `while` loop instead of a `for`

Comment: @L.Grozinger could you explain how you would replace the for loop with a while loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to stop a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346492/how-to-stop-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

```
for line in fi:
    if line.startswith("Unit"):
        un.append(line.split()[1])
        break
```